# Where is the C file with the I2C functions?

Tags: i2c, driver

I can find in raspberry pi (5), using Raspbian, in directory `/usr/include/linux` the files `i2c.h` and `i2c-dev.h`. I am looking for the .c files that have the I2C functions and use the header files.

[image: raspberry i2c files]

Looking at the [linux's I2C drivers](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/drivers/i2c), I can see that both .h and .c files are located in the same directory, so its weird to me that in Raspberry they are separated.

In which directory the .c files with the I2C functions are?

Comment: You only need the c files if you want to rebuild the kernel. For using the library, just use the h file and link to the corresponding library (not sure how that's named in this case, though).

Comment: All right, then the source files are not in the pi. In that case the question would change, I now want to know which of the files in [linux/drivers/i2c/busses/](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/drivers/i2c/busses) in linux's kernel are the ones for the I2C of the pi? Since I do not see "ARM" in the list.

Comment: @ChristianidisVasilis add your question to yout post ... a comment is not the place for it

Comment: The I²C code is compiled into the kernel (or probably a loadable kernel module). There are user space libraries to interact with these (hence the .h headers). You could also write your own using ioctl calls. Generally these are not Pi specific but common Linux and the Pi specific code in drivers.